# how can I transfer the javascript code to python code?

Tags: javascript, python

the javascript code is here:

```
var goat=6111+7380;
var hen=5548+7476^goat;
var seal=2094+4451^hen;
var rat=1687+7000^seal;
var pig=3997+8240^rat;
```

And I want get the `goat`, `hen` `seal` variable and so on in the python.
My python code is here:

```
animals = 'var goat=6111+7380;var hen=5548+7476^goat;var seal=2094+4451^hen;var rat=1687+7000^seal;var pig=3997+8240^rat;'
[eval(item.replace('var','').strip()) for item in animals.split(';')]####here is wrong
```

because eval('goat=6111+7380') is wrong, so how can I make the goal is equal the `6111+7380`?

ps：
thanks everyone. Actually I craw a website:`http://pachong.org/` to get the proxy address and the port.But the port is generated by `<script>document.write((4513^pig)+15);</script>`.And the `pig` variable is generated by `<script type="text/javascript">var goat=6111+7380;var hen=5548+7476^goat;var seal=2094+4451^hen;var rat=1687+7000^seal;var pig=3997+8240^rat;</script>`,but this javascript code change every time when I craw the index website.So I do not know how to get the port value.

```
###resultstring is something like this '(1646^hen)+19'
def getport(resultstring):
    port = eval(resultstring)
    return port

proxyurl= 'http://www.pachong.org/'
try:
    r = requests.get(proxyurl,timeout=60*4)
except:
    print 'I can not get the date of pachong.org'
if r.status_code != 200:
    print 'the status is not good. status_code is %s' % r.status_code
    return
ht = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
animals = str(ht.head.find_all('script')[-1].text)
[eval(item.replace('var','').strip()) for item in animals.split(';')]###it is wrong here

table = ht.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'tb'})
if not table:
    return
table = table[0]
trs = table.find_all('tr',attrs={'data-type':'high'})
tr = trs[0]
idlestring = tr.find_all('td')[5].text
idlestring = idlestring.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
if idlestring == u'空闲':
    # proxy_id += 1
    ip = tr.find_all('td')[1].text
    portstring = tr.find_all('td')[2].text
    patt = re.compile(u'document.write\((.*?)\);')
    if re.findall(patt,portstring):
        resultstring = re.findall(patt,portstring)[0]
    else:
        continue
    port = getport(resultstring)
    ip_port = '%s:%s' % (ip, port)
    print 'ip_port is %s' % ip_port
```

Comment: Why are you bitwise xor-ing 7476 and seal?

Comment: This is a mess. This is not the way you write in pytho. Lists are created using [] and there is no need of var while defining variable. Indentation is the key in python. Please refer somethings from here http://www.effbot.org/zone/librarybook-index.htm

Comment: @Abhi, I believe the goal is to translate from javascript notation to python notation by string manipulation (unless I misunderstand)

Comment: @JB333: AAH! The question is little ambiguous!

Comment: If the JavaScript follows a pattern, you are far better off parsing it somehow (regular expressions or a JavaScript parser) than trying to convert it to Python.

Comment: @NoBugs I do not want to bitwise xor-ing 7476 and seal,it is just because that the website does this to protect his port value.

Comment: @JB333 yes,you are correct. That is what I am doing.

Comment: @minitech thanks very much. I update my question and upload the python code. Luke Yeager gave me the good answer, so are there some other python solution?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you'd want to do this, but this works:

```
for item in animals.split(';'):
    exec(item.replace('var','').strip())
```

Comment: Perhaps. I'm not sure what he's trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like xor is `^` in both languages.

Comment: thanks. That's what I want. I should not use the `eval`, I should user the `exec`.Then I get several variables in python by javascript code.